# How to add crispy forms to bootstrap4 in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I'm having a trouble to combine bootstrap upload form with django form (crispy forms). Any idea how to put crispy forms to bootstrap form.

This is django crispy forms

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form|crispy }}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload and Download!</button>
        </form>
```

This is bootstrap form where I want to put crispy form.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Any idea how to combine these two?

Comment: what is your forms.py looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
        <form action="." method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div> <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload and Download!</button>
    </form>
```

and add this to the head of your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and in your views.py to get the file you can use `files = request.Files['file']`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!